# Moving a table all the way to the left side of the Page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, indentation, longtable

I'm having trouble with a table I have made.  It is too long and goes off of the page to the right.  I have already made the font smaller and made the page landscape.  What I need to do is have the table start farther to the left so the entire thing can fit.  Right now the table will start on the indent from the left.  In other words, having the entire table centered on the page.

Comment: Welcom to TeX.SX. A minimal working example would be great for us to have to be able to easier help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `adjustbox` package that offers `center` option. With this, every thing is centered. Further, it also offers `max width` option. If you use this, only those objects that are wider than `max width` value are resized (smaller ones are not).

Some example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\hrulefill

\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\rule{1.2\textwidth}{1ex}\\
Some text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\noindent
Some other text

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\rule{1.2\textwidth}{1ex}\\
Some text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

%% following table is not re-sized.
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\rule{0.8\textwidth}{1ex}\\
Some text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{...}` should center whatever the argument is.  I show the `\hrulefill` just to show the margin extent, demonstrating that the `tabular` is centered with respect to the LR margins.

Without seeing a concrete MWE from the OP, not much more can be said.

```
\documentclass{arlticle}
\begin{document}
\hrulefill

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\rule{7in}{1ex}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]